# STM32 controller: GPIO_SetBits doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f0

I have some problem with a STM32F030F4P6 MCU. The circuit consists of MCU itself, 3V rail connected to VDD and VDDA pins, ground connected to GND and BOOT0 pin and an LED connected to each of PA0-PA3 pins. Here is a circuit diagram (lines drawn near SV1 and SV2 connectors means external wires going to LED/power/ground/SWCLK/SWDIO pins.

[image]

Here is my code in it:

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_rcc.h"

const uint16_t PINS = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3;

int main(void)
{
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOa;
    GPIO_StructInit(&GPIOa);

    GPIOa.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIOa.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIOa.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIOa.GPIO_Pin = PINS;
    GPIOa.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIOa);

    volatile uint32_t i;

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, PINS);
    volatile uint8_t state = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        // Waste some time
        for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {};
        if (state == 1) {
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, PINS);
            state = 0;
        } else {
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, PINS);
            state = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is - LEDs connected to pins doesn't light up. I have connected a voltmeter to the output pins and debugged a program and found out that voltage goes up a little bit (to about 0.1V) each time I do `GPIO_SetBits` or `GPIO_ResetBits`, but instantly drops down to zero afterwards. Also to rule out lack-of-current issues, I changed `GPIOa.GPIO_PuPd` to `GPIO_PuPd_UP` and all the LEDs light up, but doesn't light down.

I use STM32VLDiscovery board as a debugger and CooCoox IDE.

During debugging, I can see GPIOA_ODR register bits are changing (and no longer changing if I remove the first line of `main()`), so it seems to be some problem with the output.

Can anyone give me any advise of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using the discovery board, and it has LEDs on it, you should minimally  modify your code to try to make one of the on-board LED's light first.  If you can do this, you probably have some basic circuit issue, as opposed to initialization or code.

Comment: Look at your PINS definition. It's probably zero so no pins are configured!

Comment: @ScottSeidman LEDs on demoboards works just fine. I will draw a circuit of my setup in a minute - can you please take a look?

Comment: @rfkortekaas `PINS` evaluates to 15 decimal or 1111 binary, as expected.

Comment: I see LED1 apparently connected to PA0, but I don't see any current-limiting resistor.

Comment: @Tut You mean I/O pins might have died because of current overload? I just tried to modify program to use GPIOB pin 1 which I haven't tried yet - no difference, the voltage goes up at debug step but the LED doesn't light up with 260 Ohm resistor in series.

Comment: Possibly, but in any event you will need current limiting for each LED. I haven't spotted anything else so I'm not submitting an answer.

Comment: Well, I'm left with three theories - I killed output transistors of push/pull configuration when I checked the chip with multimeter for shorts after soldering, I killed it with static charge as I wasn't wearing antistatic wristband, or I killed it with overloading by connecting LEDs without limiting resistor. First two sounds very unlikely because as I wrote above, the register values are changing as debugger tells me, but I see no output :/

I think I will try to replace the controller tomorrow if I have nothing more to do.

Comment: When you tried GPIOB, did you remember to modify the first line in main() to: RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE); ?

Comment: @Tut Sure, I changed that too - double checked it by debugging and looking at GPIOB_ODR bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
GPIOa.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
```

Should be

```
GPIOa.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
```

Very dumb. 8 hours of life wasted :(